# Getting an error message on Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial: NoMethodError in MicropostsController#create, how do I avoid getting this message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Can't add or edit a new micropost in  my toy_app (Chapter 2 of the Rails Tutorial). Before I added users and microposts with no problem. Then I specified the has_many / belongs_to relationship and ever since I'm getting:

"NoMethodError in MicropostsController#create undefined method `content' for 
  Did you mean? context context= context?" when I try to create and microposts, and a similar message when updating a micropost.

It might be worth nothing that I only had one user, and the user id was "3"... not sure why it wouldn't be 1. I've since deleted all microposts and still only have 1 user. How do I avoid this error message? If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

The Microposts Controller:

```
    class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_micropost, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /microposts
  # GET /microposts.json
  def index
    @microposts = Micropost.all
  end

  # GET /microposts/1
  # GET /microposts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /microposts/new
  def new
    @micropost = Micropost.new
  end

  # GET /microposts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /microposts
  # POST /microposts.json
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.new(micropost_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.save
        format.html { redirect_to @micropost, notice: 'Micropost was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /microposts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /microposts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.update(micropost_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @micropost, notice: 'Micropost was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /microposts/1
  # DELETE /microposts/1.json
  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to microposts_url, notice: 'Micropost was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_micropost
      @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:context, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Microposts model:

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    validates :content, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

Users model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :microposts
end
```

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
end
```

schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171222133429) do

  create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In your `micropost_params` you have permitted `context`. I assume it should be a `content`. Please check your `schema.rb` to verify what columns does your `microposts` table have.

Comment: I've added the schema.rb... I changed context to content here and also did the same in the microposts controller

Comment: I've added the schema.rb... I changed "context" to "content" in the schema.rb and also did the same in the microposts controller, but it's still not working. The message I'm getting when trying to create a new micropost is "undefined method `content' for #<Micropost:0x007f0a2423a3e0> Did you mean? context context= context?"

Comment: OK I changed all instances of "content" to "context" and it worked

Comment: You shouldn't add or modify schema.rb it updates automatically as db changes.